# Floating DIVs vertical space

Tags: css

I want to ask how to do DIVs floating left but filling vertically space of the DIVs above. I found here the solution to use Masonry JQuery plugin but I wanna ask whether it is possible to do it simply via css. If you look at the code or jsfiddle below, I would need to have BOX5 vertically aligned to the BOX2 so there is no space. Thank you

Please see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ahxjzm8/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        BOX1
        fgwertgege
        erhehethrtjh
        sthsrtjhrt
        rthrthrt
        ehertuyrtyr
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        BOX2
        sadgergwerwert
        adrfgaeghr
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        BOX3
        sefweflj
        gewrgheher5y
        tryjrtjhr
        rthrthrthrthrth
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        BOX4
        sgwhej rtjrtjktyt
        dfgherthrthrt rth rtst
        ert erterty
        ertye ryeryewe w ergerge r gertgerg
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        BOX5
        agwerheh
        etherthrtjhr
        ertherthrthrth
        ergergyhr
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.box {
    width: 500px;   
}

div.box {
    width: 30%;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the height of your column you can follow [this tutorial](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need, I want to have the columns of different height

Answer (score 0):

Setting a height or a minimum height will do it. Just add the line of code below to your CSS (div.box) and you'll be just fine.

```
min-height: 100px; /* Adjsut as needed */

margin: 0 0 5px 5px; /* Adjsut as needed to keep the spaces uniform */
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ahxjzm8/1/) to see the changes I made to yours and it's fine now

**Radical approach:** If you add the lines of code below to your CSS, it will always align but it will cut off (not show) anything that goes beyond the given value for the max-height.

```
min-height: 100px;

max-height: 200px;

overflow: hidden;
```

**jQuery solutions:** Follow the link below for a well written tutorial on CSS tricks

[Equal Height Blocks in Rows](http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/)

**Note:** Giving it a fixed height will result to problems if the supposed content exceeds the available space. The biggest of the boxes will always give you an idea of what value to set for the min-height.

Comment: Thank you, very close to what I want to look it like. I did it as you recommend but if you look at http://jsfiddle.net/9ahxjzm8/3/ you can see that the vertical space between BOX2 and BOX5 is bigger  than space between BOX3 and BOX4.

Comment: You made the min-height: 1px. Always make the value of the min-height a little taller than the size of the tallest box and you'll be just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/9ahxjzm8/4/

Comment: And when I tried to make the BOX1 content shorter it made a big space between BOX1 and BOX5 (see http://jsfiddle.net/9ahxjzm8/5/) so I am not sure if setting min-height is that solution. The same not correct result was when I tried to remove float left and use inline-block. Well, maybe there is really no simple solution and I will have to use Masonry Jquery. Should you have any more ideas, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Again, always make the min-height the same as the tallest of all your boxes. For a jQUery solution, see the tutorial here

Comment: Thanks Sleek Geek, but the point is that I don't want to have all the boxes of the same height, I don't want to have any space (except for the margins set) in vertical. Simply said, I want to have all boxes in a column to be without vertical space. I'll have a look at the tutorial but am not sure that's the issue I need to resolve.

Comment: @LukášJežek Logical reasoning, the boxes most be of equal heights for you not to have the spaces in question.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you're not setting an explicit height for the `.box` divs so their height is currently dependent on the content inside. If you don't want any space between them then you'd either have to set the same `height` or same `min-height` for `.box`